# CPU usage exceeding 100% in top command third line

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, cpu, cpu-usage

[image: top screenshot]

As seen in the above image, if you sum all the values in the third line it exceeds 100%, giving 100.1%:

```
%Cpu(s): 18.3 us, 21.9 sy, 0.0 ni, 59.6, 0.3 wa, 0.0 hi, 0.0 si, 0.0 st
```

18.3 + 21.9 + 59.6 + 0.3 = 100.1

Can anyone explain the meaning of the 3rd line of [`top`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/top.1.html)'s output?

Comment: Most system stats are collected as integral values, not as floating point values, and beyond that a lot of the values humans like to see are not collected at all, but derived on demand - e.g. CPU usage is collected as approximately "number of clock ticks spent in a specific state", which is then divided by an actual interval to derive "CPU usage in state ...". Rounding and other inaccuracies come into play. Perhaps those are rounded values for 18.26, 21.86, 59.56, 0.26... which would sum to less than 100.0...

Comment: so sum of third line in top command, always equals 100% right?

Comment: It should always be "close". But don't expect it to always be exact, due to rounding and other factors.

Answer (score 4):

Edit

The question asked above is for the net CPU consumption shown in the **3rd** line of top output.
The total sum of %CPU consumption in the 3rd line will definitely be equal to 100%. There is rounding off done for calculating individual elements, us, id, wa, sys, etc.
In this particular case, it is just a matter of round off that it is reaching 100.1%

**Below information is for the column of %CPU consumption of individual processes.**

This depends on the number of cores that you have on your system. Every core would give you a 100% value.
Therefore, if you have 4 cores, that means the total of %CPU can go up to 400%.

What do you really mean by cores?

```
grep processor /proc/cpuinfo | wc -l
```

This will give you the number of CPUs you have.
From a logical point of view (as an example Intel Core i5-3570, this could be understood from cpuinfo information also)

```
[root@localhost ~] egrep "processor|core id|physical id" /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
physical id     : 0
core id         : 0
processor       : 1
physical id     : 0
core id         : 1
processor       : 2
physical id     : 0
core id         : 2
processor       : 3
physical id     : 0
core id         : 3
```

In this there are
Physical Processors = 1

Number of cores on physical processor = 4

Number of virtual cores per physical core = None

Therefore total CPUs = 4

If there were virtual cores (such as those on Xeon processors) you would more processors.

Comment: i have 4 cores in my system, the 3rd line comprises of all 4 cores value and it will lead to a maximum of 100%, I suppose

Comment: to make it clear, the 3rd line of top command combines all the 4 cores value and rounds off to 100%, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right. The 3rd line will have a cumulative sum of 100%. I misinterpreted the question to be concerning %CPU consumption of individual processes. (Apologies! :-( )

Comment: For the latter part of this answer, explaining why individual processes can exceed 100% CPU usage, see also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/top-output-cpu-usage-100#34436) answer.

Answer (score 1):

Row three shows the cpu utilization status on server, you can find here how much cpu is free and how much is utilizing by system:

[image]